# What's the difference between ATM Vol vs ATMF Vol?

Tags: volatility

May I ask what's the difference between At-the-money volatility vs At-the-money foward Vol?

Comment: Just the referenced strike will be different- ATM: K=Spot, ATMF: K=Forward

Comment: Thanks. Why is it a market convention to use ATMF vol instead of ATM vol?

Comment: Example would be: in FX markets for longer maturities the forward would be very different from the spot due to interest rates differential, so ATMF would be more meaningful measure of money-ness. There is also Delta neutral ATM btw